# How to access test/example name in Specs2?

Tags: scala, specs2

I have some tests that share a fixture and would like to isolate the tests from each other. One way to do this would be to use the test/example name as part of a 'namespace' (eg as part of a directory path).

How can the test/example name be accessed within itself?

For example:

```
class MySpec extends Specification {
  "Something" should {
    "do something" in {
      // access String "do something"
    }

    "do something else" in {
      // access String "do something else"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you can do this two ways:

Specs2 allows you to use a string as an optional parameter to your Fragments so you can do something like this:

```
class MySpec extends Specification {
  "Something" should {
    "do something" in {
      fragmentName: String =>
        println(fragmentName) //prints do something
        ok
    }

    "do something else" in {
      fragmentName: String =>
        println(fragmentName) //prints do something else
        ok
    }
  }
}
```

There's also the hacky way (I played with this one first and just couldn't throw it away):
**UPDATED**
Here's a 'better' hacky version suggested by @Eric

```
class MySpec extends Specification {
  "Something" should {
    "do something" in {
      val fragmentName = is.examples(0).desc
      println(fragmentName) //prints do something
      ok
    }

    "do something else" in {
      val fragmentName = is.examples(1).desc
      println(fragmentName) //prints do something else
      ok
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Nice. Since it's Scala, there's gotta be a way to eliminate the boilerplate. Any ideas?

Comment: Actually, I just tried the first one and it's not working for me.

Comment: The first method should definitely work. Which specs2 version are you using? What's "not working" precisely?

Comment: Some notes about the second method. `filter(_.isInstanceOf...).map(_.asInstanceOf...)` is better coded as `collect { case e: Example => e }`. Then, there is an `examples` method doing that, so you can write `is.examples`. Finally if `is` is used it might be better to store this value in a val for performance reasons.

Comment: @Eric I updated the example but omitted any performance tuning, thanks for the tip.

Comment: @Eric, I'm using specs2_2.9.1-1.12.1. I'm getting a compilation error: scala: missing parameter type
    "do something" in { fragmentName =>
                        ^

Comment: @Eric, actually, now I'm getting: scala: No implicit view available from Unit => org.specs2.execute.Result.
      "returning true" in { fragmentName: String =>

Comment: @Eric, ah, found the problem. The last function I'm calling has a return value (yeah, this isn't good; I plan to clean it up later) so I needed to add the 'ok' at the end.